# How to set query parameter with redirect()

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like to set a query parameter when redirecting. I tried this:

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute('login/default', array('action' => 'forgotPassword', 'foo' => 'bar'));
```

It redirects to:

```
/login/forgotPassword
```

Instead of where I would like to redirect which is:

```
/login/forgotPassword?foo=bar
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The query parameter belongs to the third parameter of the URL-Methods.

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute(
    'login/default', 
    array(
        'action' => 'forgotPassword'
    ),
    array( 'query' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ))
)
```

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment. It works. I'm really tired today :P

Answer (score 0):

Plus.

To redirect a "access" or login, form you can use:

```
if (!$controller->identity()) {
  $sm = $controller->getServiceLocator();
  $router = $sm->get('router');
  $request = $sm->get('request');

  $routeMatch = $router->match($request);

  $controller->redirect()->toRoute('login', array(), 
        array( 'query' => 
                array('redir' => $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName() ) ) );
}
```

Urls will be:
/login/?redir=current-route