# How to redirect user to previous page zend framework 3

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am designing a website, that has my groups and other groups that are present on two different webpages. Both my groups and other groups have an option to see the members of each group which is redirecting to a `members.phtml` page. 
Now I want to add a back button on `members.phtml` page at the top that will go to the previous page (my groups/other groups). Is there a way to save the current url and send it to `members.phtml` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the redirect plugin and add a query param `previous` to the url. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944787/how-to-set-query-parameter-with-redirect) for an example and check the [ZF2 documentation here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-post-redirect-get-plugin) on the redirect plugin. It would become something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/members.phtml?previous=my_groups
```

In the controller for your `my_groups` route where you added the redirect url to your members page you will need to add the query param to the redirect route:

```
$previous = 'my_groups';
$this->redirect()->toRoute(
    'members', 
    array(
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array( 'query' => array(
        'previous' => $previous
    ))
);
```

Now when the `members.phtml` page is requested you can find the previous page inside the query parameters of the request object. You can easily access it in your controller like this:

```
$previous = $this->params()->fromQuery('previous'); // my_groups
```

Now you know whether the members page was accessed from `my_groups` or `other_groups` and you can render the back button accordingly.

### UPDATE

*Some extra information after your comment...*

You can find current page url for example by using:

```
$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

Or you can get the current matched route:

```
$this->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
```

And you can use this to dynamically add the previous url.

Comment: Thanks @Wilt that worked perfectly!!
But what if there are so many pages to redirect to, what could be done in such a case.
Example: Say i am shopping for something on a e commerce website,inorder to add the product to the cart, i should login first and after logging in i should be redirected to the page, where i was last seen

Comment: @ChaitanyaSairam If it worked I suggest you accept my answer. I added a comment with some extra information that might help you. There are lot's of examples on StackOverflow for such user cases.

Comment: Thanx for the info!!